# Why isn't my xslt adding the 2nd attribute to an element?

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I am writing an xslt to tranform the xml below.  When I execute the xslt against the xml the output drops the second attribute on the `<soapenv:Envelope>` element.

It should be as follows:
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.visionwebqa.com" >`

But I get:
`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >`

I thought I should just be able to include the soapenv:Envelope element in the code with the attributes and have it output as typed but it isn't working.  I would appreciate any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Here's the xml I'm working from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<PRODUCT BUILD="09-05-2019" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 18.0.3"/>
<DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="Code.fmp12" RECORDS="1" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
<METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Company" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="EdiUserid" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Param1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Param2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Param3" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Password" TYPE="TEXT"/>
</METADATA>
<RESULTSET FOUND="1">
<ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="1">
    <COL><DATA>VisionLab</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>OurQA</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>ROOur</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0199</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>vision</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

And, here's the xslt I've been using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ser="http://services.visionwebqa.com"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
    xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" exclude-result-prefixes="ser soapenv fm">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
        <xsl:variable name="fld" select="/fm:FMPXMLRESULT/fm:METADATA/fm:FIELD" />
        <xsl:variable name="ediUserid" select="count($fld[following-sibling::fm:FIELD/@NAME = 'EdiUserid']) + 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="guid" select="count($fld[following-sibling::fm:FIELD/@NAME = 'Param1']) + 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="refid" select="count($fld[following-sibling::fm:FIELD/@NAME = 'Param2']) + 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="sloid" select="count($fld[following-sibling::fm:FIELD/@NAME = 'Param3']) + 1" />
        <xsl:variable name="password" select="count($fld[following-sibling::fm:FIELD/@NAME = 'Password']) + 1" />
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.visionwebqa.com" >
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:Process>
            <ser:username><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$ediUserid]"/></ser:username>
            <ser:password><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$password]"/></ser:password>
            <ser:guid></ser:guid>
            <ser:refid><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$refid]"/></ser:refid>
            <ser:sloid><xsl:value-of select="fm:COL[$sloid]"/></ser:sloid>
            <ser:orderXml>
            </ser:orderXml>
        </ser:Process>
        </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>             
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you intend to select the values by their field name, you would be much better off exporting using the FMPDSORESULT grammar. The FMPXMLRESULT grammar is specifically intended to choose values by their position - thus allowing you to change your field names without breaking the export.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, when I export using FMPDSORESULT I get the following comment in the XML <!-- This grammar has been deprecated - use FMPXMLRESULT instead -->  Thus the reason for using FMPXMLRESULT.  Is there a reason I should ignore this?

Thanks for all your help.  You've been an invaluable resource of the years!

Comment: I believe it has been deprecated since version 7. If you still prefer to use  FMPXMLRESULT, why don't you select the COLs by their number? After all, you control their order when you export.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, namespace declarations are not attributes.

As for the reason why your stylesheet is dropping the `xmlns:ser="http://services.visionwebqa.com"` declaration from where you expect it*, it is because you told it to do so here:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="ser soapenv fm">
```

Remove the `ser` prefix from the list and the declaration will be copied to the output. And BTW, you only need it in one place, not two. If you include it in the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag, then you don't need to repeat it in `soapenv:Envelope` and vice versa.

---

(*) Do note that the declaration *does* appear eventually on the first element using the `ser` prefix. Semantically, the exact location of the declaration should make no difference to the target application.

Comment: Just a caveat, there are circumstances where the exact location of a namespace declaration DOES make a difference, notably if a namespace prefix appears somewhere other than in an element or attribute name (for example in the value of an `xsi:type` attribute). But that's not the case here.